# Find $a$ such that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have a common tangent in a common point.

Tags: calculus

$$f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R, f(x) = x^2$$
$$g:\mathbb R^* \rightarrow \mathbb R, g(x) = x + 1 - \frac{1}{ax}, a \in \mathbb R^*$$

Find $A$ = {$a \in \mathbb R^*$ | $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have a common tangent in a common point}

I know that that to find a common point of two function is equivalent to solving the equation $ f(x) = g(x)$.
So, let $$h:\mathbb R^* \rightarrow \mathbb R, h(x) = f(x)-g(x)$$ 
$$ h(x) = x^2-x-1+\frac{1}{ax}$$ 
I have no clue what to do next. I would greatly appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Hint: how do we find the tangent of a function at a point?

Comment: The tangent of a function at a point $a$ is given by the equation $y - f(a) = f'(a)(x-a)$

Comment: You want to find values $(a,x)$ such that $h(x)=0$ and $h'(x)=0.$

Comment: If you expand your equation of the tangent, for both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, when you identify the coefficients you will get that $f'(x)=g'(x)$. Together with $f(x)=g(x)$, these will form a system of two equations with two unknowns ($x$ and $a$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to find the common point of the functions, then we have to fix $f(x)=g(x)$, which is equal to 
$$x^2-x-1+\frac{1}{ax}=0.$$
If we want to find the points of the functions with common tangent, then we have to fix $f'(x)=g'(x)$, which is equal to 
$$1-2x+\frac{1}{ax^2}=0.$$
Assuming that $x\neq 0$, we get the system 
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{ccl}
x^3-x^2-x+b &=&0 \\
2x^3-x^2-b&=&0
\end{array}
\right.$$
where we defined $b=a^{-1}$. Then, we can find the solutions of this system, giving three pairs of them
$$x_1=-\frac{1}{3},\qquad x_2=0, \qquad x_3=1$$
$$b_1=-\frac{5}{27},\qquad b_2=0, \qquad b_3=1$$
The solution $(x_2,b_2)$ is not possible due to our assumptions.

Comment: Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

$$f=g,\\f'=g'$$ gives

$$\begin{cases}x^2=x+1-\dfrac1{ax},\\2x=1+\dfrac1{ax^2}.\end{cases}$$

Adding the first and $x$ times the second,

$$3x^2=2x+1$$

which has the solutions $x=1$ and $x=-\dfrac13$, corresponding to $a=1$ and $a=-\dfrac{27}5$.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that is a really neat way to solve this system.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Write your equation in the form
$$a=\frac{1}{x^2+x-x^3}$$ and use calculus.

Comment: That is what I thought of initially, but it seemed too complicated to me.

Answer (score 0):

A tangent is given by the point it is tangent to the function and it's slope. Therefore, for the two functions to share a common tangent you need to find a point that they have common (i.e., an $x$ such that $f(x)=g(x)$), and furthermore the point needs to be such that the slopes of the tangent at that point are equal too. Now the slope of the tangent is the derivative, so look for the $x$'s above that also satisfy $f'(x)=g'(x)$.